# Typesetting previously formatted text

Tags: environments

I have some text that has been formated a certain way already and I'd like to import it into latex to be able to improve the look and add more advanced formatting.

The text is basically columns separated by tabs/spaces and such

```
Part1   
    Intro 1 
            C               a             G           d
    Verse 1
            C               a             G           d
            This is a song  Just for you  I hope you  Like it too
            C               a             G           d
            and help me     make      the view        better!
```

etc...

Basically I have a text editor I can do this stuff in and use user defined colorings and all that but I have little control over advanced formatting characteristics as it's just a plain text file.

It pretty much consists of a matrix like table for the chords and lyrics with other stuff interspersed.

My goal is to be able to quickly build a song like I can already without having to deal with formatting issues that latex presents(mainly the ignoring of white spaces) or clutter up the text to make it nearly illegible unless printed to pdf.

I'm not sure if I could create some automated environment that figures out what is going on and tries to typeset it properly?

The main thing I need is something where I can type in the above text as is(with the lyrics aligned to the chords and the spacing to represent chord spacing in time, more or less).

e.g.,

```
\begin{songblock}
            C               a             G           d
            This is a song  Just for you  I hope you  Like it too
            C               a             G           d
            and help me     make      the view        better!
\end{songblock}
```

and the idea is that space(s) correlate to time in music. the in "the view" should be offset like it is shown.

The verbatim environment almost does what I want except no formatting is possible and beginning white space seems to be ignored which screws up the spacing I desire.

The following image shows about how it looks in the text editor with a colorizer applied. There are artifacts such as letters being treated as chords because the colorizer doesn't handle the "grammar".

Any ideas how to to this in the simplest way possible and get the results I want? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the `songs` and the `leadsheets` packages?

Comment: @clemens yeah, but I don't think they give me the formatting I desire. It's close and maybe they have the capabilities to do what I want, but I don't know them well enough to know. I'll look in to it and see what they can do...

Comment: the `leadsheets` package is quite flexible as far as the formatting of the output is concerned. The input would be a little different, though. I can add an answer in a few hours.

Comment: @clemens ok, thanks. I checked out the songs package and I don't think it will work. Basically doesn't really use spaces/spacing as a way to indicate time.

Comment: So the input *has* to be the way you specified in the question? Then `leadsheets` won't work either...

Comment: @clemens not necessarily in the exact format but I would have to specify the alignment and spacing for it to make sense. If it is done is some complex way it shouldn't make it less convenient the original method.

Comment: `leadsheets`' input is `^{C}This is a song  ^{a}Just for you  ^{G}I hope you  ^{d}Like it too`…